# How create mock Attribute of ServletContext?

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, mocking, mockito

I have Servlet which add users in database. Servlet use instance of module for work with database he's alias `DBJoint`. And Servlet get instance of `DBJoint` from `ServletContext`.

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        final ServletContext servletContext =
                servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

        final DBJoint joint = new DBJointHandler(
                "database_scripts",
                "authentication_database");

        servletContext.setAttribute("db", joint);
    }
}
```

And in each Servlet when I need work with database I call `ServletContext` and get `DBJoint` by key `"db"`.

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");

        try {

            final boolean success = addUserInDatabase(req);

            if (success) req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", EDIT_SUCCESS.get());
            else req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", ERR_UNIQUE_L_P.get());

            req.getRequestDispatcher(ANSWER.get())
                    .forward(req, resp);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Addition user in database.
     *
     * @return true if addition success, else false.
     */
    private boolean addUserInDatabase(final HttpServletRequest req)
            throws SQLException {

        final User user = getUserFromRequest(req);
        return getDatabaseExecutor().addUserAndGetSuccess(user);
    }

    /**
     * Extracts user's data from HttpServletRequest.
     *
     * @return user from request.
     */
    private User getUserFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest req) {
        return new User(
                req.getParameter("name"),
                req.getParameter("login"),
                req.getParameter("password"),
                req.getParameter("email"),
                req.getParameter("role")
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get executor database requests.
     */
    private ScriptExecutor getDatabaseExecutor() throws SQLException {
        final DBJoint db = (DBJoint) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");
        return db.getDBScriptExecutor();
    }
}
```

I need test my Servlet, and use mock object instead original object:

In this test I try verify what body doPost call addUser(User u) in executor of database script. But get NPE.

```
@Test
public void whenUserAddThenAddUserCall() throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {

    final AddUserServlet servlet = new AddUserServlet();

    //mock http.
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

    User user = new User("name", "login", "password", "email");

    //mock database.
    ScriptExecutor executor = mock(ScriptExecutor.class);

    DBJoint joint = mock(DBJointHandler.class);
    when(joint.getDBScriptExecutor()).thenReturn(executor);


    final ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    //In this place I get NPE but why?
    context.setAttribute("db", joint);

    servlet.doPost(request, response);

    verify(executor).addUser(user);
}
```

Why I have `NullPointerException`? How test this class? Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include these as well

```
ServletContext context = mock(ServletContext .class)
when(request.getServletContext()).thenReturn(context );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `request.getServletContext()` on the `request` object which is a mock.

Mocked objects do no provide real method implementations. Instead of the real getServletContext() implementation, a stubbed version of the method is called returning null.

A mock should be told what it needs to return when a method is called on it, you need to define behavior just like you did for the DBJoinHandler mock.

To solve the NPE, do something like this:

```
when(request.getServletContext()).thenReturn(context);
```

where `context` could be a ServletContext mock.

Comment: `when(executor.addUserAndGetSuccess(user)).thenReturn(true);` I get `IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized` My AddUserServlet call `getDatabaseExecutor()` and it's fail. I need mock ServletContext due to `getDatabaseExecutor()` will be called.

Comment: You need to define behavior for the getServletContext() method when it's called on the `request` mock. Try something like this: `when(request.getServletContext()).thenReturn(mock(ServletContext.class));`